# sliding on 45° on XY axis (translate X and Y same value at the same time)

Tags: transforms

There is a way to move on x,y,z, but is there a way to move on a 45° angle between 2 axis? like sliding X and Y at the same time from the same value?

Comment: Local Z axis if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

Of course there is.
Just drag-select both X and Y axis and enter the value.

[image]

Comment: can you show me exactly the combination you use? I try the same, but It doesn't select both of them, only one each time....

Comment: No combination, just mouse cursor over the two fields... :).

Comment: well when I do it, I can go everywhere but I don't have the 45 degree forced :/

Answer (score 3):

Or you can create custom orientation.

1. Select two vertices in 45° angle and set orientation to *Normal*
2. Click `+` to create a custom orientation
3. Now you can switch to it any time.

*Create custom orientation*
[image]

*Use custom orientation*
[image]